# Getting weak pointer to derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, visual-c++, smart-pointers

I have a bunch of derived classes stored as shared pointers, I was wondering if there is any way of getting a `weak_ptr` to the object from inside the object?

I've tried using the `shared_from_this()` function but the problem is that since it's a derived class, when I make the base class inherit from `enable_shared_from_this`, when the derived class calls `shared_from_this()` it gets a `shared_ptr` of the *base class* **not** the *derived class* which I can't turn into a `shared_ptr` of the derived class

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you turn the `shared_ptr<Base>` into a `shared_ptr<Derived>`? Can't you use `dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_ptr)`?

Comment: @Torbjörn I didn't realize that `dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_ptr)` existed, it's exactly what I needed thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Torbjörn said, using the `dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_ptr)` fixed this problem as it allowed me to convert `shared_ptr`'s down in inheritance, something that isn't directly allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Usign CRTP you can achieve it:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct B: std::enable_shared_from_this<T> {};

struct D: B<D> {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B<D>> b = std::make_shared<D>();
    std::shared_ptr<D> d = b->shared_from_this();
    std::weak_ptr<D> w = b->shared_from_this();
}
```

If you want to have a common, non-template base class, you can rely on techniques like the double dispatching, as in the following example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct D1;
struct D2;

struct S {
    void doSomething(std::weak_ptr<D1> weak) { std::cout << "D1" << std::endl; }
    void doSomething(std::weak_ptr<D2> weak) { std::cout << "D2" << std::endl; }
};

struct B: std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
    virtual void dispatch(S &) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct M: B {
    void dispatch(S &s) override {
        auto ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<T>(shared_from_this());
        s.doSomething(ptr);
    }
};

struct D1: M<D1> {};
struct D2: M<D2> {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<D1>();
    S s;

    b->dispatch(s);
}
```